# Dynamic Linking Issue

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-dynamic-links

I am working on dynamic linking in firebase, I have achieved the whole functionality of dynamic linking, but the main issues is that, im passing query parameter id while generating dynamic link but when i try to retreive dynamic link there are no query parameter in that. It return null or empty map.

Here is code:

Creating Dynamic Link:

```
  buildDynamicLinks(String title, String image, String docId) async {
    final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
      link: Uri.parse("https://www.infusiblecoder.com/?id=$docId"), ///Here im passing id as a query parameter
      uriPrefix: "https://darwishkhan.page.link/fanspot",
      androidParameters: const AndroidParameters(
        packageName: "com.example.fanspot",
        minimumVersion: 30,
      ),
      iosParameters: const IOSParameters(
        bundleId: "com.example.app.ios",
        appStoreId: "123456789",
        minimumVersion: "1.0.1",
      ),
      navigationInfoParameters:
          NavigationInfoParameters(forcedRedirectEnabled: true),
      socialMetaTagParameters: SocialMetaTagParameters(
          description: '', imageUrl: Uri.parse(image), title: title),
    );
    final dynamicLink =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildLink(dynamicLinkParams);
    print(dynamicLink);
    Share.share(dynamicLink.toString(), subject: 'Checkout this venue!!');
  }
```

Code to retrieve dynamic link:

```
FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink
    .listen((PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLinkData) async {
   ///Here im trying to fetch id
  if (dynamicLinkData.link.queryParameters.containsKey('id')) {
    String? id = dynamicLinkData.link.queryParameters['id'];
    NavigationHelper.pushRoute(navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        VenuesDetailsView(venueID: id.toString(), index: 0));
  }
}).onError((error) {
  // Handle errors
});
```

Comment: Do you plan on passing more than 1 query parameter?

Comment: Yes i will pass more than one parameters but testing on one and not even getting that one parameter

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing seem to be wrong with your code.** So am not sure why its not working.

Here are some possible way around.

1. Try using paths instead i.e "https://www.infusiblecoder.com/$docId" ==> "dynamicLinkData.link.path".
2. You could also try build a shortlink instead.
3. I put together some snippets a. [link generator class](https://gist.github.com/theodoremca/b12481f4e252ec09a2a5f001fe582d9c)
   b. [use-case-code-sample](https://gist.github.com/theodoremca/732384421de8a706a858ebee55c7f219)

I hope these help. Good luck.